# ERROR for site owner: Invalid site key

Tags: recaptcha

I created a reCAPTCHA key and disabled `Verify the origin of reCAPTCHA solutions`, yet I am still getting there error `ERROR for site owner: Invalid site key`.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right so it appears the reCAPTCHA unverified keys simply don't work and they don't seem to give a shit about fixing it. Ended up just specifying the domains.

Answer (score 7):

Same here. It seems to work for me if I add at least one domain or *localhost* in the Domains list, but then uncheck the option under **Domain Name Validation**.

Comment: This is a bizarre issue, and an even more bizarre fix, but the above answer worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the case, but what I encountered before, was that I used http://example.com instead of example.com.

For me it worked after I removed "http://"