# reCAPTCHA:"ERROR for site owner: Invalid site key"

Tags: recaptcha

I tried to set up reCAPTCHA, on my page by following the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro).  I signed up for an API key pair and was issued a public key and a private key.  It was not clear, to me, how the private key should be used and I could not find more information about it.  It does not appear to be used on the page where reCAPTCHA is called.

I edited my page and put

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

before the closing `</head>` tag on my HTML template.

I also put

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my-public-key"></div>
```

where I want my reCAPTCHA widget to appear.

When I load my page, I get the message

> Cannot contact reCAPTCHA. Check your connection and try again.

I also see the reCAPTCHA widget with the text

> ERROR for site owner: Invalid site key

I have checked similar questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47218606/error-for-the-site-owner-google-site-owner), where the answer says the key is probably invalid but I have just generated it.  I also saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44631918/error-for-site-owner-invalid-site-key) but I did not disable

```
Verify the origin of reCAPTCHA solutions
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to ensure your site is added in the domains section of the google reCAPTCHA page where you generated the API key and save. Then test again. That worked for me.

Comment: That was part of it.  I had added my IP address instead of the site name.    Also, there was a file, insert.php, that needed the correct private key.

Answer (score 114):

It wasn't obvious to me initially, but you have to supply your site key in 2 places:

1. In the *render* querystring parameter in the script source tag
2. As the first parameter of the javascript *execute*() method

[image]

Comment: How could I overlook that? Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, even today, the reCaptcha docs are... under developed.

Comment: It was obvious to me, but as I was trying v2 and then v3, I forgot to change the key on both places..

Comment: I'm not sure if we have more than one subdomain we must create new keys. I did it and following this answer I fixed.

Comment: @Matthew your image got corrupted. Please mention the places name where we can add the site key.

Answer (score 10):

In my case it was using a wordpress site,

And I had chosen version 3 of captcha and it turns out the wordpress only supported version 2.

Comment: Although I am stuck while integrating V3 in WordPresss but I strongly doubt what you are saying and thinks WordPress support V3 because WordPress is just simple PHP so there is no hard and fast rule if PHP supports it then WordPress also supports it.

Comment: It has nothing to do with being a Wordpress site.

Comment: I have just implemented v3 in wordpress, it works fine.  Issue is most likely you are using a plugin.

Answer (score 5):

I also face same problem from google reCAPTCHA console your project uncheck

1. Verify the origin of reCAPTCHA solutions
2. Send alerts to owners

both,then see from your contact form, its working from me just try it

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Entrepreneur Wordpress theme which came with Formidable. I went to the reCAPTCHA Admin Console and created the Site and Secret Keys for "V2 Checkbox."

At first it wasn't working and I was getting the "ERROR for site owner: Invalid site key" message but figured out that the reason why was because I had put the "http://" before my domain.

After trial and error, I discovered that deleting the old reCAPTCHA for that domain, then creating a new one without the "http://" worked perfectly! Not sure if having or not having the "www." would matter for any other users.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have added domain without https://www and added only site domain help me. Remove https://www works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with reCAPTCHA v3 on my blog on Wordpres 4.5. When I replaced reCAPTCHA v3 with reCAPTCHA v2 the issue has gone.

Answer (score 1):

Double check that you are using the "Site Key" and not the "Secret Key" inside the Google ReCaptcha settings. They look quite similar, so it's easy enough to make this mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue in my React app,recaptcha v3 give me error,reCapcha v2 works fine.Just change the version from v3 to v2,copy and paste site key and works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I also had to change from the `reCaptcha` type: v3 to v2. It's worked in my case. I think the reCaptcha docs are underdeveloped

Comment: Where did you make this change?

Comment: can you explain what you actually did ?

Comment: I Downgraded the reCaptcha version. In 2021, I was unable to use v3. But now, you guys can look into it.. Maybe it works.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I'm using Contact Form 7 plugin inside my WordPress CMS-based website, the problem was because I'm filtering/removing the query string from the enqueueing scripts e.g. `script.js?**v=1.2**`:

```php
function mb_remove_script_version($src)
{
  $parts = explode('?', $src);
  return $parts[0];
}

add_filter('script_loader_src', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\mb_remove_script_version', 15, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Google stopped supporting TLS 1.0, make sure you making request with TLS1.1 or TLS 1.2

Use  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; for .NET 4.5 and lower version

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Wordpress Contact Form plugin. Be sure that you have put correct domain at reCAPTCHA configure page. It should be without `http://` or `https://`. For example, `google.com`. Regenerate api keys and update it in Admin/Contact/Integration. Then you will see recaptcha icon in the page bottom corner

Comment: Incorrect: According to reCaptcha: `A valid domain requires a host and must not include any protocol, path, port, query or fragment.`

Answer (score 0):

I removed  following `<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="***site-recaptcha-key****"></div>` from the page and V3 still sending the reply as intended and the error is gone now. Tested and it does work as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I had simply forgotten to add the recapcha credentials to my production ENV file, thus only supplying "none" in the script tag.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are using the correct recaptcha version. As of writing this post there is

[Google reCAPTCHA V2](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create)

[Google reCAPTCHA V3](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create)

[Google reCAPTCHA Enterprise](https://console.cloud.google.com/security/recaptcha)