# recaptcha v3 - ERROR for site owner: Invalid key type

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha

I am getting the following error in Google Recaptcha V3 on my website.

> **ERROR for site owner: Invalid key type**

[image]

**I am using following method to verify captcha:**

1. adding script

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=API_KEY"></script>
```

2. on submit verify:

```
$('.submit-e-way-bill-registration').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = this;
    if ($(self)[0].checkValidity()) {
        grecaptcha.ready(function () {
            grecaptcha.execute('API_KEY', {
                action: 'homepage'
            }).then(function (token) {
                console.log(token);

                console.log('google captcha initiated');
                $('[name=captcha_token]').val(token);

                var data = $(self).serialize();
                $('.save-button-ewb').prop('disabled', true);
                $.post('/api/submit-e-way-bill-registration.php', data, function (result) {
                    $('.save-button-ewb').prop('disabled', false);
                    console.log('status');
                    if (result.status == 'success') {
                        $('.success-message').show();
                        $('.submit-e-way-bill-registration').hide();
                    } else {
                        $('.error-message').show();
                        $('.submit-e-way-bill-registration').hide();
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    }
});
```

This used to **work before (about 3-4 months ago)** this way. Now when I am checking I am getting the above error.

**Can anyone tell me what is wrong in the code???**

Comment: I'd guess there's something wrong with the key, not the code. Can you go back to your ReCaptcha dashboard and check the key, or generate a new key?

Comment: I checked that, but there is nothing wrong with key!! @Rup

Comment: @Rup but a strange thing is I can still submit the form and validation is working. But error  is still showing

Comment: Some other suggestions here: [reCAPTCHA:“ERROR for site owner: Invalid site key”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48600034/243245). If they don't help you'll probably have to ask Google.

Answer (score 5):

I've met that kind of error a few days ago.
I solved that problem by generating the correct ReCaptcha site's client-key.
In my opinion, your script wants google ReCaptcha v2, but you are using v3.
Please have a check this screenshot. This solved my problem.
[image]

If you are using the node module in react, get more detail from this [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-recaptcha).